# How do I install drivers for TP-Link AC1300?

Tags: 16.04, drivers

When I ordered this TP-Link AC1300 Wireless Dual Band PCI-Express Adapter (Archer T6E), I looked into customers reviews and they said it worked fine with no drivers on Ubuntu. I didn't have a CD/DVD player on my desktop so I (on a laptop with a DVD drive) copied and pasted the DVD support disk content on to a USB drive and used that. But when I tried to run `autorun.exe` it puts up archive manager and says `An error occurred while loading the archive`
Ubuntu verison- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Output from: `lspci -vnn`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 11)
Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard (one of many) [1849:8168]
Kernel driver in use: r8169 
Kernel modules: r8169
```

I am fairly new to Ubuntu (1 month) and have learned alot (sudo commands) and now know that windows is overpriced and that ubuntu is better in most fields.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: *.exe files are executable on Windows but not in Ubuntu. So you don't need to run autorun.exe.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command. Your output shows only the Ethernet adapter.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to run it just by setting proprietary drivers? I need to know before buying it

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with AC1300 Archer T3U in an Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13.0-28-generic.

I used the next repository from MaxG87.

https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu

you clone it with

`git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu`

enter to the download directory and use:

`sudo make`

It will start to create the driver and after five minutes when the construction is done, use the next command:

`insmod 88x2bu.ko`

All of this is in his own github page.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

You could build the linux driver from source, but it requires a good amount of linux experience

My repo here:

```
sudo apt-get install git linux-headers-amd64 build-essential
git clone https://github.com/nyetwurk/linux-wifi-88x2bu-driver
cd linux-wifi-88x2bu-driver
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 88x2bu
```

Verified to work with hostapd (AC1300 Archer T4U) 802.11ac

```
ID 2357:0115 TP-Link 802.11ac NIC
```

Comment: This repository does not compile. It breaks in `rtw_mlme_ext.c`.

Comment: Apologies, I have since moved over to https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu which is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this post on ubuntu-forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2314548.html) which mention the wifi-card you are using. So I'm going to instruct you to enable `proprietary drivers`.

`Proprietary Drivers` are not generally available by `sudo apt-get update`. You should go to

> system settings -> software & updates

[image: Software Updates]

and click on the `Additional Drivers` tab. There you should see proprietary drivers available for use.

[image: Proprietary Softwares]

In your case, details of software should indicate that the driver is for `"Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)` Card. You should tick the radio button which will enable the use of the driver. Then apply changes.

I hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: I cannot speak for anyone else, but this doesn't work for me because that Additional Drivers window is empty and just says "no additional drivers available". Maybe Ubuntu needs to be told to download some additional drivers first; but if so then those steps are missing - and this is for a wifi stick so it should be assumed that the user probably can't download those drivers directly to the computer in question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an Ubuntu forum and I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi running OctoPi but I thought it might help some of you since OctoPi is also based on Debian.

After trying possibly everything, this worked for me:

https://github.com/TheRealSadRed/Driver-Linux-Tp-Link-Archer-T3U-Plus
sudo apt install gcc bc -y

```
git clone https://github.com/TheRealSadRed/Driver-Linux-Tp-Link-Archer-T3U-Plus.git
cd Driver-Linux-Tp-Link-Archer-T3U-Plus
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

*Now you can attach the device, and it will be automatically recognized. (Sometimes it requires a reboot).*

*If you do a kernel upgrade/change you will probably have to do the above procedure again.*

Be sure to install bc before compilation. Probably it isn't necessary since it worked even if I got a `bc command not found` at the start of the compilation, but I just like having no errors at all.